# awk print the number of columns between a selected range from awk

Tags: awk, line

1. I have the next line for show a range of text from file. It's correct, but i would like to show the number of line at the first of each line. I prove with different s options without results.

```
    buffer=`awk -v desde="$DESDE" -v hasta="$HASTA" 'NR>=desde&&NR<=hasta' "$FICH"
```

The output of the command below is the next:

```
1:20220413:20:Curso Astrología:5:Vicente Ferrer

1:10042022:0:Donación instituto Samye:103:Propia

14:20220428:0:Candelario Yeshe Nyimpo Inc:9:Dudjom Tersar

1:20220512:60:Ayuda por el Hambre y Violencia:6:Vicente Ferrer

 Total Lineas: 43 | Total Pag: 2  |Buffer: De 0  hasta 26 | 27
```

But i would like the next result:

```
1 1:20220413:20:Curso Astrología:5:Vicente Ferrer

2 1:10042022:0:Donación instituto Samye:103:Propia

3 14:20220428:0:Candelario Yeshe Nyimpo Inc:9:Dudjom Tersar

4 1:20220512:60:Ayuda por el Hambre y Violencia:6:Vicente Ferrer

 Total Lineas: 43 | Total Pag: 2  |Buffer: De 0  hasta 26 | 27
```

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples please try following `awk` code. I have improved your attempted code, also taken care in case line number crosses `hasta` value it will simply exit from program to save some cycles and time.

```bash
awk -v desde="$DESDE" -v hasta="$HASTA" '
NR>hasta{ exit }
NR>=desde && NR<=hasta{
  if(/^ Total/ || !NF){print; next }
  if(NF){print ++count,$0}
}
' "$FICH"
```

---

---

***2nd solution*** with your shown output run following on your shown output in case you want to do so:

```bash
awk '/^ Total/ || !NF{print;next} NF{print ++count,$0}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```bash
awk '                 ##Starting awk program from here.
/^ Total/ || !NF{     ##Checking condition if line starts from space Total OR its NULL then.
  print               ##Print that line.
  next                ##next will skip all statements from here.
}
NF{                   ##Checking condition if NF is NOT NULL for current line then:
  print ++count,$0    ##Printing count value(increasing it with 1 before printing) followed by current line value.
}
' Input_file          ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: The second solution it's correct but the only think it's that i created a pagination and always the count here is from 1 to the end of output and i need to  count from a external variable because the buffer change every press a key and of course, i need the not reset the count,. Thank you a lot for your quicly answer.

Comment: @ValentinLuque, sure, you could try my 1st solution which is built on your attempt, I had edited it so try my latest/current one now. It should work fine, let me know how it goes, cheers.

Comment: @ValentinLuque, my 1st solution takes shell variables into `awk` and uses them as per your requirement in it.

Comment: I understand your exemple but i try to put on my context for understand this global situation about how i programmed the script. I have a global variable $MOSTRAR_LINEA_INIT  that count all lines that is  a text file. Also i have a global var $MOSTAR_LINEA, in the exemple is the number 27 , that when i press a key the buffer var change according to terminal lines. You can go up of the file or down with press one key or another. Then the buffer change in this 2 situations. In your trick every page that i show output l have  {1 ..to  total} lines from that buffer but not from the total file.Tnk!

Comment: @ValentinLuque it sounds like the example you provided in your question doesn't adequately demonstrate the real problem you're trying to solve. Ask a new question and include a more truly representative [mcve] if you need more help.

Comment: For a better explainer example i post a new question about this doubt here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74513602/awk-print-the-number-of-row-between-a-selected-range-from-variable-in-awk-and